# Is it possible to INSERT/UPDATE 8,000,00 records in MySQL within few minutes through Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to INSERT/UPDATE if exists in MySQL for 8,000,00 records through Node JS.

I am using Node JS with "mysql" package.

My queries are: `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` type.

For almost 5000 queries of this type separated by semicolon I am sending it to database using `connection.query()` method. Some values of the query come from a text file that contains 8,000,00 records. I am reading the file using Node JS readline

Is it possible to insert all this things withing few minutes may be 10 minutes?

Comment: thanks @lonut for editing my question ...

Comment: as in insert in database? or just stored in an array inside nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES, it depends on IO, not language or platform**

Comment: This should be posted as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @Ionut Why? It's an answer.

Comment: @BaiJiFeiLong you mean it depends on Hardware of the machine like RAM or CPU, Hard Disk..???

Comment: @BaiJiFeiLong I am using a Core i3 machine, 4GB RAM and 500GB HDD

Comment: @anijit I mean the connection from your node.js app and your database server.Maybe your database server is launching in another machine.